# using python 3.5 saving csv from url drops CR and LF

Tags: python, csv

I'm using Python 3.5.0 to grab some census data. When I use my script it does retrieve the data from the url and saves it but the file that was saved can't be imported to SQL because it somehow dropped the {CR}{LF}. How can I get the file it saves able of being imported to SQL?

```
try:
    url = 'https://www.census.gov/popest/data/counties/asrh/2014/files/CC-EST2014-ALLDATA.csv'

    headers = {}
    headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0'

    req = urllib.request.Request(url,headers=headers)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    respData = resp.read()

    saveFile = open('Vintage2014.csv' ,'w')
    saveFile.write(str(respData))
    saveFile.close()

except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Comment: By drops do you mean `adds` or `removes` ?

Comment: Thanks Anand, Martin noticed it was not being dropped, they were not in the file format originally. He used a decode('latin -1') and the formatting came out correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, the file you are trying to download does not contain `CRLF` only `LF`.

You could use the following approach to convert the bytes to a suitable string. This should also result in you getting `CRLF`:

```
import urllib.request

try:
    url = 'https://www.census.gov/popest/data/counties/asrh/2014/files/CC-EST2014-ALLDATA.csv'
    headers = {}
    headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0'
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    respData = resp.read()

    with open('Vintage2014.csv', 'w') as saveFile:
        saveFile.write(respData.decode('latin-1'))

except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks Martin, that actually fixed my data pull. I'll have to look up what the decode('latin-1') means so I can better understand what the code is doing. Thanks again, that worked out perfect!